# Display tick mark image when click on the name field in the RecyclerView?

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm displaying the list of items in a RecyclerView. If I click on the item name I have to make the tick mark image visible. If i click on the name the image is visible but while I am scrolling the image position is changing continuously. Please can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Here is my code for RecyclerViewAdapter

```
    public class Category_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Category_adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Activity context;
    boolean sample = false;
    ArrayList data = new ArrayList<>();



    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txt_name;
        ImageView img_select;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txt_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_category_new);
            img_select = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_select);
            img_select.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txt_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    img_select.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.e("name", "Holder Name" + txt_name.getText().toString());
                }
            });


        }



    }

    public Category_adapter(Activity con, ArrayList data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = con;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.category_adapter, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);


        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        holder.txt_name.setText(data.get(listPosition).toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size() ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Boolean> clicked = new ArrayList<>();
```

> and save the value clicked.

and onBindView holder put something like this:

```
if(clicked.get(position)){
    view.setvisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
 }else{
    view.setvisiblity(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: where we have to save the value of clicked.

Comment: in arraylist by         clicked.add(position,bool);

Comment: all the best... :)